# Android Bitmap from visible area of scrollview

Tags: android, bitmap, scrollview

I have a static helper method that takes a View and returns a Bitmap of the View. (The real method modifies the bitmap before returning it).

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View targetView) {
    Bitmap bitmap =
            Bitmap.createBitmap(
                targetView.getWidth(), 
                targetView.getHeight(), 
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    targetView.draw(canvas);

    ....

    return bitmap;
}
```

I'd like to modify this for a special case of when targetView is a ScrollView. I'd like to only grab the section of the ScrollView that is visible instead of the whole ScrollView. I can't seem to come up with any examples.

Answer (score 0):

Calling `getDrawingCache()` on the `targetView` might be a possible solution:

```
if (targetView instanceof ScrollView) {
    targetView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    bitmap = targetView.getDrawingCache();
}
```